# Can I call setState() from a setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got the following code in my component:

- I begin a bounce effect by calling setState with `setPosition(-0.08)`
- Then I'm using a **ref** to store a `setTimeout` with a call to `setPosition(0)` after 350ms.

```
function changeImage(dir) {

  const isBouncing = useRef(false);
  const bounceTimeout = useRef(null);
  // ... some other code

  if (dir === 'LEFT' && selected === 0) {
      isBouncing.current = true;
      setPosition(-0.08);
      bounceTimeout.current = setTimeout(()=> { 
        isBouncing.current = false;
        setPosition(0);
      }, 350);
      return;
    }
}
```

It works as intended!

**QUESTION**

Is there any reason why I shouldn't be doing this (calling `setState` from a 
`setTimeout`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `setState` from a `setTimeout`. That is for example one of the ways to achieve animation.

But in your case you should move your code to `useEffect` hook, otherwise it may cause side effects.

And you also need to clear the timeout on unmounting

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if (bounceTimeout.current !== null) {
      clearTimeout(bounceTimeout.current)
    }
  }
}, [])
```